# Override LinqToSql class property

Tags: linq-to-sql

One of the fields in a table in my database stores string values delimited by '|'. Of course, when I generated a Linq data model from the table using the VS designer, a string property has been created for the mentioned field. I want to override that property so as to expose the stored values as a more convenient string array (splitting them by '|').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is create a partial class (all LINQ-to-SQL classes are partial by default) of your class and exposing a property with the desired behaviour. Something like this:

```
 public partial YourClass {

     public string[] SpecialProp { get { return OtherProp.Split('|'); } }
 }
```

Comment: but how do you constrain entry?